# ActionBar tabs with MapView

Tags: actionbarsherlock, android-mapview

I've created app using SherlockActionBar tab. One with my tabs contains MapView (Google Maps v2). Currently I have problem when I change tabs (screen below):

[enter link description here](http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/6631/rpc.png)

Next tab should contain ListView. Sometimes context second tab loaded correctly. Also I have problem with swiping my MapView. Currently I can only swiping up and down direction. I hope that somebody help me.

My code:

- myfragment.xml

  ```
  <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
      android:id="@+id/mapview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:clickable="true" />
  ```
- TabFragment_Map.java

  public class TabFragment_Map extends SherlockFragment {

  ```
  MapView mapView;
  GoogleMap map;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);

      mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
      mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      map = mapView.getMap();
      map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
      map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

      try {
          MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
      } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);

      return view;
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
      mapView.onResume();
      super.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
      mapView.onDestroy();
      super.onDestroy();
  }

  @Override
  public void onLowMemory() {
      mapView.onLowMemory();
      super.onLowMemory();
  }
  ```

  }
- MainActivity.java

  public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

  ```
  ViewPager mViewPager;
  TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

  String TabFragment_Cafes;
  String TabFragment_Details;

  //Settery & gettery używane w mechanizmie przesyłania informacji pomiędzy fragmentami
  public String getTabFragment_Cafes() {
      return TabFragment_Cafes;
  }

  public void setTabFragment_Cafes(String tabFragment_Cafes) {
      TabFragment_Cafes = tabFragment_Cafes;
  }

  public String getTabFragment_Details() {
      return TabFragment_Details;
  }

  public void setTabFragment_Details(String tabFragment_Details) {
      TabFragment_Details = tabFragment_Details;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
      mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
      setContentView(mViewPager);

      final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
      bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
      bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

      mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
      mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Mapa"), TabFragment_Map.class, null);
      mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Kawiarnie"), TabFragment_Cafes.class, null);
      mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Szczegóły"), TabFragment_Details.class, null);

      if (savedInstanceState != null)
          bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      //super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
      outState.putInt("tab", getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
  }

  public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
      private final Context mContext;
      private final ActionBar mActionBar;
      private final ViewPager mViewPager;
      private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

      static final class TabInfo {
          private final Class<?> clss;
          private final Bundle args;

          TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
              clss = _class;
              args = _args;
          }
      }

      public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
          super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
          mContext = activity;
          mActionBar = ((SherlockFragmentActivity)activity).getSupportActionBar();
          mViewPager = pager;
          mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
          mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
      }

      public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
          TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
          tab.setTag(info);
          tab.setTabListener(this);
          mTabs.add(info);
          mActionBar.addTab(tab);
          notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

      public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}

      public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}

      public void onPageSelected(int position) {
          mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
      }

      public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
          Object tag = tab.getTag();
          for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
              if (mTabs.get(i) == tag)
                  mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
          }
      }

      public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}

      public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}

      @Override
      public Fragment getItem(int position) {
          TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
          return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
      }

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
          return mTabs.size();
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom viewpager that intercepts the swipes

```
package com.ecs.google.maps.v2.component;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {

        // When using Maps V1       
//        if(v instanceof MapView){
//            return true;
//        }
//        return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);

        // When using Maps V2
        if (v.getClass().getPackage().getName().startsWith("maps.")) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);        
    }

}
```

Put this in your layout :

```
<com.ecs.google.maps.v2.component.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

And the swiping gestures should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have some example with use that technique?